# How to pass output of a command in cmd to a txt file using python?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, operating-system

Is there a way through which I can pass the output of a CMD command to a `.txt` file using python?

Something like this :

```
 import os
 os.system('cmd /c "netsh wlan show profiles"')
 #output=OUTPUT
 output_file=open(outputfile+'.txt','w')
 output_file.write(OUTPUT)
 output_file.close()
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import subprocess
out = subprocess.getoutput("ls -l")
print(out)
```

Now you can just pass on this output to a `txt` file using `open()` and `file.read()` method

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the output to a temporary file. The following is a simple example:

```
import os
os.system('cmd /c "netsh wlan show profiles" > tmp.txt')
```

Then you can just read the tmp.txt file and see the output. This solution is based on your code.

There are other options such as using `subprocess`, you can read more in the following link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

Answer (score 0):

Try this library https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Method `subprocess.run()` should do the job. It allows to capture stdout and stderr when param `capture_output=True`

Answer (score 0):

There is already a similar question here: [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello, World!"])
```